# Sql Field Recursive Limit Exceeded: Model with a parent reference to another of itself

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

So far. I can understand that there is a sql/database querying issue related to this. The symptoms of the bug is also a long wait time, typical of a recursive method. Although, imo it shouldnt be recursive, it should just list categories that match the parent category. I am doing this all from the admin part at the moment, and I am not quite sure how to work with django enough to know how to solve this issue correctly, at the moment.

So the rundown:

- Slow response to an error (recursive function behaviour within database?)
- Occurs when accessing the admin/category/create page (GET request)
- Something to do with having a parent 'category' in itself

**edit: I think it may have to do with looking into itself, when it shouldnt.*

Here is the code, all in the same module:

```py
# models.py
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        related_name="sub_categories",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    featured_product = models.ForeignKey(
        "Product", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="+"
    )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        if self.parent_category:
            return f"{self.parent_category} - {self.title}"
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["title"]

# admin.py
@admin.register(models.Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ["featured_product"]
    list_display = ["title", "products_count"]
    search_fields = ["title"]

    @admin.display(ordering="products_count")
    def products_count(self, category):
        url = (
            reverse("admin:backend_product_changelist")
            + "?"
            + urlencode({"category__pk": str(category.pk)})
        )
        return format_html(
            '<a href="{}">{} Products</a>', url, category.products_count
        )
    
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).annotate(products_count=Count("product"))
```